# Random Graph Generator for C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if by any chance there are some random graph generators for C# like [this one](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generators.html)? The downside of this is that it is only for Python.

By graphs I mean a random interconnection of nodes having a start node and an end node and a dense interconnection between nodes [this paper has an algorithm](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2011-Uppsala/papers/edbt/a30-nobari.pdf). Maybe there is a C# version implemented for free?